# Get notification from Reachability when the app is not running

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, reachability

I used [Reachability library](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift) for checking that th iPhone reachs to the internet. If the app is running, It receive fine the notification. My question is how to make the app receive the notification when It isn't running?

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(AutoCheckin.reachabilityChanged(_:)),name: ReachabilityChangedNotification,object: reachability)
        do{
            try reachability?.startNotifier()
        }catch{
            print("could not start reachability notifier")
        }

func reachabilityChanged(note: NSNotification) {

        let reachability = note.object as! Reachability

        if reachability.isReachable() {
            if reachability.isReachableViaWiFi() {
                logMessage("Reachable via WiFi: ")
                print("Reachable via WiFi: ")
            } else {
                logMessage("Reachable via Cellular: ")
                print("Reachable via Cellular")
            }
            self.pushLocalNotification()
        }else{
            logMessage("Network not reachable")
            print("Network not reachable")
        }
    }
```

And also I need to send a local notification if there is an internet.

Comment: The simple answer: you can't.

Comment: I think you need to describe what you're trying to achieve. Why would you care about network status changes when your app isn't running and cannot need the network?

Comment: I need to know if I am in my company by entering in its wifi. So I need to check in case wifi is changed.